# How was non-uniform yellowish cast created on BW photos of Charles Lucima?

Tags: post-processing, photoshop, black-and-white, reverse-engineering

I don't know if it's allowed to ask this type of questions here. If not please let me know.

How was created following non-uniform yelowish cast on BW photo (author is Charles LUCIMA) ?

[Image here - not safe for work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n56JJ.jpg)

At first, after looking at a/b channels in LAB color (**[see here](http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7061/6974088085_25bf51ef7c_b.jpg)**), I though it's solid color layer with layer mark where darker areas are more yellow than bright ones. But after I tried it's not the case.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It seems a local painting.

Comment: It seems unlikely because almost 100% of his photos are post-processed like that.

Comment: It could be some subtle split-toning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After number of experiment it seems like it was two-color gradient applied on separate layer via "Soft Light" mode.

Answer (score 0):

I think Paolo and Joe are right.  You can get something similar with split toning, setting the shadows to a reddish-orange, and leaving the highlights neutral.

But if you overlay the a/b channels (good idea by the way) with the greyscale image, the color doesn't correspond with all the dark areas of the image.

It is strongest in the shadows of her arms, legs and torso, but there is little or no color in the shadow area under her neck.

There is also some color in the highlights, for example the upper right corner.

He may have started with split toning, or a solid color layer, and picked a channel to produce an inital mask, then did local painting on the mask.  Or he may have brushed the whole thing in.  It doesn't seem to exactly overlay the lines in the image